# How to render / preprocess list of entity reference nodes?

Tags: theming, nodes

I hove a content type that editors can 'attach' related nodes to.

When I 'theme' / 'style' nodes of this content type through `view mode` everything is basically fine: the related nodes are rendered as teasers and I can style them as I like.

Now I need to wrap the list of related nodes in an extra class e.g. 'related-nodes' according to the output of another field. For example the editor chooses 'round corners' from a list field, then the css class "rounded" should be added to the wrapper of the list of related nodes should.

I am aware I can remove the entity reference field from the display settings and preprocess it through `template.php`. But then ***how*** do I preprocess the list in `template.php`? So far I just don't know how to actually access / handle it.

In `devel` tab I do get the array of related items. I could of course loop through that array and re-build node by node thruogh `node_load` – but since I only want to wrap that loop re-rendering each node feels wrong.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences) may be able to help with that

Comment: Thank you! But I actually need to add classes according to conditions previously read from another field…

Comment: Ah ok - a quite straightforward option would be to implement `hook_node_view()` in a custom module and add a `#prefix` and `#suffix` to the field element (prefix of `<div class="foo">`, suffix of `</div>`)

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Clive comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157598/how-to-render-preprocess-list-of-entity-reference-nodes#comment190247_157598), [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences) module may be able to help with that.

A quite straightforward option would be to implement `hook_node_view()` in a custom module and add a `#prefix` and `#suffix` to the field element (prefix of `<div class="foo">`, suffix of `</div>`)